# Why is this property of integral true?

Tags: calculus

$\lim_{ \Delta z \rightarrow 0}(\int_{z}^{z+\Delta z}(F(x,y,t)dt))/ \Delta z = F(x,y,z) $

Can anyone show me why this is true? Thank you!

Comment: There is something wrong in what you have written. The right hand side is a function of $t$, but on the left hand side you integrate over $t$...

Comment: I have fixed the error.

Comment: That looks like the FTOC, or is that what you're trying to prove?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus

Comment: @Max Thank you, I see now.